# Not getting the api returns value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I took two projects. one for apis and another one for Displaying the apiresult.

This my api controller:

```
 public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Index()
        {
            return "Hello world";
        }
     }
```

and this is my Displaying Controller :

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

and the view for Index Controller is as bellow:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<input type="submit" value="Get Value" id="btnSubmit" onclick="GetData();" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetData() {
        var uri = 'http://localhost:50951/api/Home';
        $.ajax({
            url:uri,
            type: "Get",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

When i click the GetData button it is calling the api and the api returns the string value. But in javascript i did not get the api returns value.

Comment: your API solution and MVC solution are separate project?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Either do:

1) Edit the `Index()` method to:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Index()
{
    return Json("Hello world", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

or

2) Remove the `dataType: "JSON"` from the jquery ajax call.

Comment: i  tried by removing dataType: "JSON"  but still i did not get api returns value

Comment: What happens if you browse to `http://localhost:50951/api/Home` with Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Hello World</string>

Comment: I have to apologize, returning a JsonResult is not possible in WebAPI (only in MVC). Try to replace `dataType = "JSON"` with `contentType = "application/json"` in the jquery ajax call.

Comment: That's strange. I tried it myself and it is working perfectly (with `dataType:"JSON"`). Maybe there is some other code with side effects?

Comment: No. i took two different projects.one project contains Apis and another project Contains Api result displaying logic. Need to change any settings.??